# Android: Layout to image saving, saved image is blank sometimes

Tags: android

There is a part in my application when user takes a photo. 
Then the user can save the image or retake one.
When the save button clicked the following method called.
The problem is that sometimes the saved image is blank.
Although the "custom" image i'm seeing is the image i want to save.
The image is extracted from a Frame layout which contains a ImageView and a TextView at the bottom of the image.
The image is saved at SD card pictures/AppName/

```
private void saveImage() {

    sqimage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    sqimage.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = sqimage.getDrawingCache();
    File image = new File(imageRoot, imageName);
    boolean success = true;


    if (image.exists()) {
        image.delete();

    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(image);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, output);
        output.flush();
        output.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        success = false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        success = false;
    }

    if (success) {


        Log.i(TAG, "JPEG saved at " + imageName);
        new SingleMediaFileConnector(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), image);
        // sqimage.destroyDrawingCache();
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra(EXTRA_PHOTO_FILENAME, imageName);
        getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
    } else {
        getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
    }

    getActivity().finish();
}
```